# Issues with x-ticks in log-scale wit matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a figure in log-scale and would like to set the x-ticks manually to [0.5, 1, 2]:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ax = plt.gca()

ax.set_xscale("log")
ax.set_xticks([0.5,1,2])
ax.set_xticklabels([.5,1,2])
ax.set_xlim([0.5,2]) # issue causing line
```

However, it automatically also sets one to 6*10^-1, which I can't get rid off.
Even asking `ax.get_xticks()` doesn't show this x-tick. How can I get rid of the unwanted tick?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like a minor tick. Try adding

```
ax.set_xticks([], minor=True)
```

Output:

[image]